# Why don't bookmarks appear when using \nofiles?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, auxiliary-files

#### Background

After a document has been compiled fully, activating `\nofiles` usually causes references and other entities in next run to be the same as in the previous run. This is necessarily exploited when putting multiple logical pages onto a single physical page using the `pgfpages` package, as otherwise references and links would be to the wrong pages.

The usual compile workflow is to compile normally (without `\nofiles`), then add `\nofiles`, then compile again.

#### Bookmarks

The `bookmark` package boasts about having the ability to get bookmarks right in a single run. However, no bookmarks are created at all when `\nofiles` is active, even if previous runs contained bookmarks.

**Q**: How can I get the `bookmark` package to work when using `\nofiles`?

(Note I already have **an** answer to this question, and am providing the answer for the benefit of others. And maybe someone can improve upon it.)

#### MWE

(It is not necessary to use `pgfpages` to demonstrate the behaviour, though my real use case is with that package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}

% compile first with \nofiles commented out
% then comment it back in, and compile again
%\nofiles
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{\maxdimen}

\begin{document}
\section{first}
abc
\section{second}
def

\end{document}
```

When compiling this as is, the bookmarks for the sections appear fine. When subsequently uncommenting the `\nofiles` line and compiling again, the bookmarks are missing, but they are still wanted!

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation

The `bookmark` package still makes use of the `aux` file mechanism in LaTeX, but the actual work of including the bookmarks in the final PDF file is done when the `aux` file is read at the **end** of the document, not when it is read at the beginning. This is how it can achieve its results in a single run (though it is not clear why it needs to use auxiliary files at all - it doesn't appear to rely on "whatsit" nodes as it uses `\immediate`).

The problem with this is that when `\nofiles` is active (`\if@filesw` is `\iffalse`), LaTeX does not re-input the `aux` file at the end of the document (even if the file already exists - again it is not entirely clear why). Therefore, the bookmarks never get written. Further, the `\bookmark` command is largely disabled in this mode and does not do enough set up for the `aux` file commands to work.

#### Possible fix

The following code shows patches to both the `bookmark` package and to LaTeX itself, which should allow preserving the bookmarks when using the method of compiling enough times without `\nofiles` and then activating `\nofiles`. This works by getting LaTeX to input the `aux` file at the end of the document even when `\nofiles` is active; I am not 100% sure that this has no unintended side-effects. (As usual when using `\nofiles`, if references or citations have changed then you will get warned of changes and told to re-run latex, but obviously this will never stabilize as the `aux` won't change on subsequent runs.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}

% compile first with \nofiles commented out
% then comment it back in, and compile again
%\nofiles
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{\maxdimen}

%% the patch for \nofiles support for bookmark package
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dopatchbkm}{%
    \xpatchcmd{\bookmark}{\if@filesw}{\iftrue}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}%don't deactivate \bookmark in \nofiles mode
    \xpatchcmd{\bookmark}{\@mainaux}{\m@ne}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}%but still don't write to files (write to log instead)
    \patchcmd{\enddocument}{\if@filesw}{\iftrue}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}%still input the aux file at the end
    \patchcmd{\enddocument}{\@@input\jobname.aux}{\@input{\jobname.aux}}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}%for protection in case the aux file doesn't actually exist (don't want a non-recoverable error)! Thanks to David Carlisle.
}

\AtBeginDocument{% delay to \begin{document} in case \nofiles is used AFTER this point
\if@filesw
\else
    \dopatchbkm
\fi
}
\makeatother
%% end patch for \nofiles support for bookmark package

\begin{document}
\section{first}
abc
\section{second}
def

\end{document}
```

Comment: possibly main bad thing that will happen is that if you do not have a .aux file then you will get the non-recoverable error  `! I can't find file '____.aux'.`  You should at least change the `\@@input \jobname.aux` to use `\@input{\jobname.aux}` so it doesn't try to input a missing file. Similarly if references or citations have changed since `\nofiles` used you will get warned of changes and told to re-run latex but obviously this will never stabilize as the aux won't change

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Many thanks for the suggestions, I have edited them in. If those are the only likely problems then I am happy with this.